# Using Ansible loop to create multiple users: Undefined error

Tags: ansible, rhel, user-accounts

I am using the following `ansible` code to create multiple unix user accounts

`---
- hosts: test
  become: true
  tasks:
      - name: more complex items to add several users
        user:
         name: "{{ item.name }}"
         uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
         groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
         state: present
        with_items: "{{ user_details }}"`

I am storing the user information by using a separate a variable file as below

```
  `cat /etc/ansible/vars.yml
   ---

   user_details:
       - { name: testuser1, uid: 1002, groups: "admin, logs" }
       - { name: testuser2, uid: 1003, groups: logs: }`
```

To execute above playbook , I tried with both the commands below

```
   sudo ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/userloop.yml -e /etc/ansible/vars.yml
   sudo ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/userloop.yml
```

but both commands are failing with below error

```
 fatal: [host-003]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'user_details' is undefined"}
 fatal: [host-004]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'user_details' is undefined"}
```

How to resolve the issue ? I want to maintain a separate variable file to store the user information rather then putting them in the same playbook file  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **@** while passing the vars.yml. Hence, the ansible is not reading the file. Try the below command. It works for me.

```
sudo ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/userloop.yml -e @/etc/ansible/vars.yml
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also refer the multiple variable files in playbooks like below

```
- hosts: all
  become: true
  vars_files:
      - /etc/ansible/vars.yml
  tasks:
      - name: more complex items to add several users
        user:
         name: "{{ item.name }}"
         uid: "{{ item.uid }}"
         groups: "{{ item.groups }}"
         state: present
        with_items: "{{ user_details }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of variables is in the column "Parameter" of the module [user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/user_module.html). Try the structure of the data below

```yaml
    user_details:
      - {name: 'testuser1', uid: 1002, groups: ['admin', 'logs']}
      - {name: 'testuser2', uid: 1003, groups: ['logs']}
```